# Is there a way to move data labels to the side of a stacked column in HighCharts?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a stacked column chart that has a target number and an actual number.  I'm using a percentage stacking so that they all have the same visual weight, but show how close we're getting to goal.  I'm trying to put the labels for the goal to the right of the columns.  Like this:
[image]

The only way I could figure out to do this is using a x value for the series dataLabels

```
"series": [{
    "name": "Target",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "rgba(185,74,72, .5)",
    "borderColor": "rgba(185,74,72, 1)",
    "borderWidth": 2,
    "data": targetsAdj,
    "dataLabels": {
         x:55,
         verticalAlign:'top',
         "formatter": function() {
             if (this.series.index == 0) return targets[this.point.x];
             else return this.y;
         }
     }
},{
    "name": "MCBF",
    "type": "column",
    "data": mcbf,
    "color": "rgba(47,126,216,.5)",
    "borderColor": "rgba(47,126,216,1)",
    "borderWidth": 2,
    "zIndex": 10
} ]
```

The problem is that when the chart is resized, the columns change width and the labels are then in the wrong spot.
[image]

Is there a better way to do this?
Also, any suggestions on cleaning up the handling of the percentages would also be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/3MhT4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set dataLabel to the right side, using `align: 'right'`. Then x-offset will be fixed, see: http://jsfiddle.net/3MhT4/6/

```
        dataLabels: {
            x: 40,
            align: 'right',        
            ... 
        }
```

Comment: For some reason I thought the align and x values were mutually exclusive.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The problem here, of course, is your `x:55` is hard-coded for the initial size of the chart.  I can't see anyway to make it dynamic.  How I would handle this is to drop the `dataLabels` all together and instead use the [text renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text) to annotate the chart.  This will give you the freedom to place/style the labels however you want.

Here's a function that'll place the labels directly to the right of each bar:

```
var posDataLabel = function(chart){
    var cW = chart.series[0].columnMetrics.width;
    var someLabels = [];
    $.each(Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data, function(i,dP){
        var xPos = dP.plotX + cW/2 + chart.plotLeft + 4; // x position is center column postion + 1/2 the width + the start of the plot area
        someLabels.push(chart.renderer.text(targets[i], xPos, 20));
        someLabels[someLabels.length-1].add();
    });
    // remember the last labels and remove them on redraw
    if (this.lastLabels){
        $.each(this.lastLabels, function(i,j){
            $(j.element).remove();
        });
    }        
    this.lastLabels = someLabels;
}
```

Calling this function from the `chart.load` and `chart.redraw` events should get you pretty close.  Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3MhT4/4/).